# batching matrix multiplication for Eigen Tensors

Tags: c++, eigen, eigen3

I would like to batch matrix multiplication by taking slices of large tensors.

Say I have A of shape [N, 1, 4], B of shape [N, 4, 4]. I would like to first slice them along batch dimension, getting [b, 1, 4], and [b, 4, 4] which is not necessarily contiguous, but getting results of shape [b, 4] by doing matrix multiplication in batches. Is there a way to do that using Eigen?

Comment: Why would you want to do this rather than multiple the tensors, then extract the submatrices?

Comment: @Mansoor sorry I guess I wasn’t clear. The slicing part does not really matter(should have left out that), what I want to do essentially is just multiply tensor of shape (b, 1, 4) and (b, 4, 4) in batches.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is an efficient way to perform  batch matrix multiplication for Eigen Tensors but one solution might be mapping tensor pages as matrices and performing general matrix multiplication:

```
#include <Eigen/Dense>
#include <unsupported/Eigen/CXX11/Tensor>

typedef Eigen::Tensor<double, 3> Tensor3d;

inline void batchedTensorMultiplication(const Tensor3d& A, const Tensor3d& B, const std::vector<int>& batchIndices, Tensor3d& C)
{
    Eigen::DenseIndex memStepA = A.dimension(0) * A.dimension(1);
    Eigen::DenseIndex memStepB = B.dimension(0) * B.dimension(1);
    Eigen::DenseIndex memStepC = C.dimension(0) * C.dimension(1);
    int outputBatchIndex = 0;

    for (int batchIndex : batchIndices)
    {
        Eigen::Map<const Eigen::Matrix<double, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::Dynamic>> pageA(A.data() + batchIndex * memStepA, A.dimension(0), A.dimension(1));
        Eigen::Map<const Eigen::Matrix<double, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::Dynamic>> pageB(B.data() + batchIndex * memStepB, B.dimension(0), B.dimension(1));
        Eigen::Map<Eigen::Matrix<double, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::Dynamic>> pageC(C.data() + outputBatchIndex * memStepC, C.dimension(0), C.dimension(1));

        outputBatchIndex++;

        pageC.noalias() = pageA * pageB;
    }
}

int main() 
{
    constexpr int N = 50;
    std::vector<int> batchIndices = { 0,1,2,3,4,9,10,11,12,13 };

    Tensor3d A(1, 4, N), B(4, 4, N), C(1, 4, (int)batchIndices.size());

    batchedTensorMultiplication(A, B, batchIndices, C);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using [Eigen Tensor chip](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/unsupported/eigen_tensors.html#title87) and a loop:

```
template <typename Device>
const Eigen::Tensor<float, 3> batched_matrix_multiplication(const Device &device, const Eigen::Tensor<float, 3>& A, const Eigen::Tensor<float, 3>& B) const
{
    typedef Eigen::Tensor<float, 3>::DimensionPair DimPair;
    Eigen::array<DimPair, 1> dims{DimPair(1, 0)};
    const int batch_size = A.dimension(0);
    const int dim1 = A.dimension(1);
    const int dim2 = B.dimension(2);
    Eigen::Tensor<float, 3> output(batch_size, dim1, dim2);
    for (int i = 0; i < batch_size; ++i) {
        output.chip<0>(i).device(device) = A.chip<0>(i).contract(B.chip<0>(i), dims);
    }
    return output;
}
```

The result of this function is a 3-rank tensor. You can then use [reshape](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/unsupported/eigen_tensors.html#title83):

```
const Eigen::array<Eigen::Index, 2> dims = {Y.dimension(0), Y.dimension(2)};
auto Z = batched_matrix_multiplication(_device, X, Y).reshape(dims);
```